# winmail.dat atttachment parsing in JavaMail library

Tags: java, attachment, winmail.dat

When we sent a pdf attachment from outlook, while receiving in JavaMail library, we received the attachment as winmail.dat format, how to parse the attachment from winmail.dat in JavaMail library.

Tried to parse by using JTNEF library but could not convert.

Comment: There is no winmail.dat parsing in the JavaMail library, and asking for library suggestions is off-topic.

Comment: I tried one solution by using JTNEF library, which didn't worked out , so I'm asking for solution to parse winmail.dat and not for library.